# How do I setup sending emails from Windows Azure through my company server?

Tags: email, vpn, cloud, azure

In my Windows Azure web role I need to send emails. Looks like one of the options is to use my company SMTP server. I asked our admins - they say I have to join the Azure role into our corporate VPN for that.

How do I do that joining? Do I use Azure Connect?

Answer (score 1):

If your SMTP server is behind a firewall, Azure Connect would be a way to get around that. Using Azure Connect, you can create a virtual network group with your Web Role instances + one or more servers on-premises. In this case, you'd have the Connect Agent most likely running on the SMTP server itself, allowing your role instances to directly address the server.

Keep in mind: Those same admins will probably have final say regarding what gets installed on production servers on-premises, so they may or may not allow this configuration, even though it's a secure connection limited to the specific servers you include in your Connect Group (editable in the portal).

One alternative is to use a 3rd-party email service such as SendGrid. In fact, SendGrid just announced a partnership with Windows Azure, and they're providing a free tier with 25,000 emails / month. More info on that promotion [here](http://blog.sendgrid.com/sendgrid-in-the-cloud-with-microsoft/).

If you download the [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396), you'll see a lab called Connecting Apps with Azure Connect. This is a good starter tutorial.

Comment: I considered using Connect - looks like it allows to join non-Azure machines into an Azure VPN. What I need is to join an Azure machine to my corporate VPN - the opposite thing. Will Connect do that?